# Vscode intellisense give weird hint when input brackets for function, shift+enter would autofill

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, intellisense

Check the Gif for the situation:
[image: Check the Gif for the situation]

I use C# in Unity, There was no problem like that before, it only appeared in recent months, it seems after new unity-vscode package was installed.

This is annoying because I also installed the extension called[Colonize].
It could let me input [Shift+Enter] to quickly add [;] at line end.

When this hint appeared, if input [Shift+Enter], the first line[Acceleration Event] of the hint-list would be auto-filled in my round brackets of the funciton ....

I already searched the hot-key menu and it seems no hot-key was related to this...
I also searched a lot of threads about intellisense, but no topic about this.

Does anyone know how to close this weird hint when I input a function with no parameters?

I also hope to know how to let [shift+enter] not auto-fill the first hint in the list.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

- Open VS Code user settings with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd>
- Search `settings.json` and choose user settings from suggestions.
- Then add `"editor.suggestOnTriggerCharacters": false` to the end of the file.

Worked for me and I have the same Colonize add-on as you do.